# SVG Scaling and Coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, coordinates, scaling

This is my first SVG project, and I’m not a programmer, but I dabble in interactive infographics. My previous experience in this area comes from working with ActionScript.

I’m using plain SVG (no Raphael, D3, etc.) and trying to create an interactive barchart. After some initial difficulty with the SVG coordinate system and scaling, I found some code online that handles the postscaling translation:

```
<text x="x_coord0" y="y_coord0" transform="scale(x_scale, y_scale) translate(-x_coord0*(x_scale-1)/x_scale, -y_coord0*(y_scale-1)/y_scale)" …>text</text>
```

And I converted it into this JavaScript:

```
var translationfactor = ((0 - y_position)*(y_scalefactor - 1) / y_scalefactor);
var matrix = "scale(1," + y_scalefactor + ") translate(0," + Number(translationfactor) + ")";
targetbar.setAttribute("transform", matrix);
```

The problem is that I need the bars “translated” back to the chart’s baseline, not the original locations of their topmost points. Currently the correctly scaled bars are hugging the top of the chart:

http://billgregg.net/miscellany/upsidedown-barchart.png

I’ve tried several fixes, including plugging the bars’ ”missing height” into translationfactor (the bars start out the full height of the chart and get scaled down dynamically). Nothing has worked. Part of my problem is that, besides being new to SVGs, I can stare at that code all day and my brain still can’t parse it. Multiplying negative numbers is too abstract and at a fundamental level I just don’t “get” the math, which of course makes modifying the code difficult.

My questions:

(1) What’s the fix for the code above to position the bars back on the baseline of the chart?

(2) Is there a more transparent, more pedestrian way of accomplishing the translation? My first thought along these lines was that if a bar’s height is reduced to 40% of its original value, then multiplying the original Y coordinate value by 250% should reset the bar to its original location (at least its topmost point), but that doesn’t seem to work.

(3) Is there a way to set a bar’s point of origin to its bottom? In Flash it’s possible, though as far as I know it’s a manual, not a programmatic task.

(4) Is there a method similar to .localToGlobal() in ActionScript that would allow me to avoid having to mess with the local coordinate system at all?

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes there is matrix math going on and it can be hard to get your head around the pre and post multiplication of arrays.

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but reading between the lines, it sounds like you are wanting to provide graph coordinates in their raw(ish) form and have the SVG scale and position them for you(?)

If that's the case, then I think the solution is simpler than what you think.

Assuming I'm right, we'll start with something that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <g transform="">

    <rect x="0" width="1" height="5" fill="red"/>
    <rect x="1" width="1" height="11" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="2" width="1" height="12" fill="orange"/>
    <rect x="3" width="1" height="8" fill="blue"/>

  </g>

</svg>
```

Where `x` is obvious and the bar length is in `height`.  `y` defaults to 0, so we don't need it here.

You basically want to know what goes in the `transform` to scale and position the bars on your page.  The fact that your graph is "upside-down" helps a little.  Because the origin in an SVG is at the top left.

First apply a scale. Let's make the bars 20 pixels wide, and scale the lengths up by 10.

```
  <g transform="scale(20,10)">
```

Next you want to position the graph on the page.  Let's put the top-left corner at (40,40).
In SVG the transformations are concatenated in order (post-multiplied) so in order for the translation to be what you specify and not be multiplied by the scale, you should put it first.

```
  <g transform="translate(40,40) scale(20,10)">
```

So the final SVG looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <g transform="translate(40,40) scale(20,10)">

    <rect x="0" width="1" height="5" fill="red"/>
    <rect x="1" width="1" height="11" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="2" width="1" height="12" fill="orange"/>
    <rect x="3" width="1" height="8" fill="blue"/>

  </g>

</svg>
```

The above has been simplified by assuming you have already subtracted the values from your base 20%.  If you wanted to keep the pure raw values, it's possible, but things get a bit trickier.  You would need to either tinker with both the `y` *and* `height` value of each bar, or use clipping to hide the part of the bar above 20%.

For "right way up"/normal graphs.  All you need to do is make the y scale negative and translate the graph so that the **bottom**-left is where you want it.

```
  <g transform="translate(40,140) scale(20,-10)">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, BigBadaboom, for taking the time to compose such a thorough answer.

Sorry if I wasn't clear, but this is for an interactive SVG. I've uploaded a copy now, something I should have done in the first place:

http://www.50laboratories.com/miscellany/demographicclout14.svg

The bar graph mostly works except for the postscaling bar placement problem mentioned above (bars hanging from the top of the chart) and a couple lines of code that I haven't added yet that will zero out the bars for the years before a state has been admitted to the union.

Comment: My assumption so far has been that SVG code in XML format can only fire once when the SVG loads, and any code that would be user-initiated would have to be in the form of a JavaScript function. Am I wrong? Apart from the transform command, I'm not sure how I'd translate the code above into JavaScript.

Comment: Another problem you'll notice if you're using Firefox (originally I didn't intend to ask about it in this post) is that the bar positioning isn't stable. Although the chart is drawn correctly on load, as you click on states and cause it to be redrawn the bars drift upward and outside of the chart. As far as I can tell this bug doesn't occur in Chrome. I haven't tested it in other browsers yet.

Comment: It may be possible to do what you want using the SVG animation functions, but it would be much easier with JS.  Since you are using JS, you should be able to set the bar position and size to exactly what you want.  Eg. height = (20-housePercent) or whatever.